# Version Control "Referenced Packages" metadata when developing managed package

Tags: managed-package, isv, version-control

Is there a good reason to add all the "Referenced Packages" metadata to version control when developing a managed (extension) package?

Or is there a good reason NOT to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't include it, especially if they are managed packages, its information that cannot be changed in the development org and can be recreated at will if needed. In addition the Apex Class files are all empty anyway. Your Apex classes, triggers, pages etc all have meta data files that record the version of the dependent packages your using, so its not as if you even need these files to track that. So for me, for these reasons its not needed and I don't include it in source control.